# Can Estimation board 2.0 include mis-sized stories in the unsized column?

Tags: sdk, rally, appsdk2

If the stories are mis-sized how can we not ignore it but add it to the unsized column?

Answer (score 0):

That's a good idea.  I think the old Estimation Board (the one currently in the app catalog in the product) used to bucket mis-sized artifacts in the closest bucket- something estimated 4 would show up in the 5 column.

It should be fairly straightforward to make these changes.  I'm filing a github issue to track this request.

https://github.com/krmorse/EstimationBoard/issues/2